# Rendering each day using json data

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have a web service that returns a color for each day like this:

```
({"total_rows":"96","rows":[
  {"row":{"date":"2013-01-01","airqualityindex":"50","categorycolorinteger":"-16718848"}},
  {"row":{"date":"2013-01-02","airqualityindex":"45","categorycolorinteger":"-16718848"}},
  {"row":{"date":"2013-01-03","airqualityindex":"57","categorycolorinteger":"-256"}},
  {"row":{"date":"2013-01-04","airqualityindex":"36","categorycolorinteger":"-16718848"}},
  {"row":{"date":"2013-01-05","airqualityindex":"42","categorycolorinteger":"-16718848"}},
  {"row":{"date":"2013-01-06","airqualityindex":"51","categorycolorinteger":"-256"}}
...]})
```

I want to shade each day cell's background color using the categorycolorinteger returned from this web service. I think I may be able to do that with dayRender but I haven't found a good example of how to do this.

Thanks, Amy

Comment: What format are those colors supposed to be stored in?

Comment: Color format is argb. I convert to RGB using this function.
`function argbToRGB(color) {
    return '#'+ ('000000' + (color & 0xFFFFFF).toString(16)).slice(-6);
}`

Comment: Markup is: `<DIV id="tab_6">
    <div id="calendar">
    </div>
   </DIV>`  

Javascript is: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
   left: 'prev',
   center: 'title',
   right: 'next'
  },
  theme: true,
  dayRender: function(date, element, view) {
   // can modify 'element' and add a class to it
  }
    })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your object above and set the background-color appropriately. Something like this:

```
dayRender: function(date, cell) {
             // loop through your object here
             // here the date 2013-03-01 and the color red are passed from your loop
             if($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') === "2013-03-01")
                cell.css('background-color', 'red');
           }
```

Let me know if that helps!